# Play audio in the background using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, avaudioplayer, morse-code

Hello guys I have a problem ..

I have basically a method that compares you with 3 if that type of letter (letter by letter taken from a label). (If a point, a line or a space). 
depending on the type launches a code that reproduces a specific sound. 
the problem I have is that, launched this method, the app freezes until it has finished cycleFor.

I wonder, is there a way to get him to do in the background or in another thread? is enough for me that the user can do something else while is in progress this code.

I can not even with another button that stops the player, how could I do?

I state that I am a novice and I know scarcely what are the thred

Thanks in advance for your help, sorry for the English

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)transmitSound:(id)sender {

NSString *code = self.labelCode.text;
//labelCode is the label that contains the code to be translated 


for (int i = 0; i <= [code length]; i++) {
    NSString * ch = [code substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    //I need to compare a letter at a time

    if ([ch isEqual:nil]) {nil;}
    //should avoid error .. or is it useless?


    if ([ch isEqual: @"."]) {
 NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
 resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/beepCorto.mp3"];
 player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL      fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:nil];

        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];

            NSLog(@"beepCorto");
            sleep(1);
           //aspect 1 seconds because if I don't, you hear nothing

            [player stop];

        }


        else if ([ch isEqual: @"-"]) {

            if (player) {
                if ([player isPlaying]) {
                    [player stop]; } }

            NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
            resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/beepLungo.mp3"];
            player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:nil];
            [player setDelegate:self];
            [player play];


            NSLog(@"beepLungo");
            sleep(1);

            [player stop];
        }


        //se trovi un " "  (spazio)
        else if ([ch isEqual: @" "]) {

            if (player) {
                if ([player isPlaying]) {
                    [player stop]; } }

            NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
            resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/silenzio.mp3"];
            player =[ [AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:nil];
            [player setDelegate:self];
            [player play];


            NSLog(@"silenzio");
            sleep(1);

            [player stop];

        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The app freezes because you're asking the app to freeze. The problem is this:

```
    [player play];
    NSLog(@"beepCorto");
    sleep(1);
    //aspect 1 seconds because if I don't, you hear nothing
    [player stop];
```

You're telling the app to sleep for 1 second every time. This is very bad, your app can become unresponsive and crash.

You need to rewrite completely your function to prevent the app from freezing, using AVAudioPlayer's delegates... or just run your code on a different thread.

EDIT: To implement the delegate do the following:

1.- Make your class conform to the [AVAudioPlayerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008068) protocol. To do this you modify the declaration.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

2.- Make your class implement the protocol's `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` method.

```
(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    // This function will be called when the 'player' has finished playing
    beepCount ++
    NSString *ch = [code substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(beepCount, 1)];
    // ...
    // Here you can instantiate the next AVAudioPlayer to play the next beep
    // Don't forget to set the delegate again
}
```

3.- Every time you create an AVAudioPlayer object set it's delegate to `self` (as you are already doing)

You need to keep an additional variable in you class to keep track of the beeps that have been playing. In my example above, that would be the variable beepCount (just an example, you can handle it in some other way)

Comment: Thanks I did not know that was a bad thing .. Thanks for the information. 
There is another problem, I do not know how I could start using delegates AVAudioPlayers. Sorry but I still am a newbie .. could you give me some help?

Comment: I understand the code, the problem is that once started the cycle does not stop until it has finished. I would like to know if you can stop a cycle that is in progress with another button.